# passwd for ldap users

Tags: active-directory, redhat, ldap

I'm trying to enable linux hosts to authenticate against an active directory server using port 389 and tls.  I seem to have that much working, but the users cannot change their passwords via passwd.

I was on the assumption that during a passwd change it'd bind with the username and old password rather than the binddn/bindpw in ldap.conf, but i may be wrong. If that's the case, how to i get it working, because the test\ldap domain user does not have permissions to change other user's passwords, and i don't want to give it that permission as this config file will be on every client.

This is on rhel5 (and if i get it working, rhel4 also)

Here's my config files on the client:

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.2 TESTSRV.TEST.COM TESTSRV
192.168.0.1 WIN-JERS4CCKFGM.TEST.COM WIN-JERS4CCKFGM
```

/etc/ldap.conf

```
debug 0
```

uri ldap://WIN-JERS4CCKFGM.TEST.COM/
base cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com
ldap_version 3

binddn TEST\ldap
bindpw Pwldap1
bind_policy soft

scope sub
timelimit 30

nss_base_passwd cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com?one
nss_base_shadow cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com?one
nss_base_group cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com?sub
nss_schema rfc2307bis
nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount User
nss_map_objectclass posixGroup group
nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory UnixHomeDirectory
nss_map_attribute gecos name
nss_map_attribute ou description

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap

hosts:      files dns
```

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   files ldap
automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so

/etc/pam.d/passwd just has the usual 3 include system-auth lines in it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Kerberos or Samba winbind at all? Or are you just trying straight LDAP?

If the latter, your /etc/ldap.conf file should have a series of 'pam_*' parameters that seem to be missing. In particular '**pam_password ad**' is necessary to specify ADSI as the password change protocol. You may also need 'pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName' (+ others)

Personally I've always just bound the Linux machine using winbind, then changing passwords is as done with 'net ads password'

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using winbind (it caused us alot of glitches due to it breaking), but i'm open to using krb5. On the krb5 front, i have kinit working to grab a ticket, but i wasnt sure a) how to tie krb5 into this, b) how to use krb5 to grab a ticket for cron jobs etc and at login time of the user, so for now i disabled krb5